Best way to create an encrypted swap file in Linux without entering a password
After a Debian 12 install without LVM and with plain ‘/boot’ and LUKS encryption for ‘/’ and ‘/swap’ with passwords, ‘/swap’ now needs to be configured without passwords, for example using ‘/dev/urandom’.
Meanwhile, I have seen so many solutions that are just incomplete or contain errors or are outdated that I wonder what is actually the best way to solve this properly anno 2024 with a current distribution.
Based on responses, I would like to answer this question. The question then is:
How to simply but properly configure a swap partition from the base on a Linux system without hibernation with encryption and without asking for a password during system start.

How do you propose that this should work?

LUKS gave me a hard time indeed. After-all it doesn't make that much sense so the dm-crypt approach is what I finally chose.

From man crypttab(5):
EXAMPLES
           # Encrypted swap device
           cswap /dev/sda6 /dev/urandom plain,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,hash=sha1,swap


Example with luks (/etc/crypttab):
cswap /dev/sdb /dev/urandom luks,swap

uuid may be tricky PARTUUID works for me
cswap PARTUUID="985d4f1d-b478-5943-bf3b-0ee87517ed68" /dev/urandom luks,swap

to get the PARTUUID:
fdisk -l # get the path to the you want to use (i use /dev/sdb here)
fdisk /dev/sdb
# press g to create a partition table (use all suggested defaults)
# then press n to create a new partition (use all suggested defaults)
# then press w to write the changes to disk (this may destoy data on the disk, if the disk have some in before)
blkid /dev/sdb1  # this should now return the PARTUUID, if not try a reboot for easy fix

I tested it on a Debian 12 VM.

This is a) wrong and b) doesn't address the question at all.

Did i misunderstood the question? Can you explain what is wrong from what i wrote? Thanks

This is a system where deliberately no hibernation is active. The point with the swap partition is that normally no one is interested in its contents except a cracker. So encryption of the swap partition is desirable but the LUKS password used is totally irrelevant, it may be generated automatically or via a key file. The higher purpose of the question is, of course, how to make it as easy and good as possible and thus how to avoid having to enter a password for the swap partition every time.

So i totaly misunderstood, sorry. Edited the answer.

Thanks. Strictly speaking, it does not answer the question because it was about LUKS and not dm-crypt. That's why I changed the question and now your answer is correct. :-)
You could reduce the question to a choice between LUKS with a password in a key file or dm-crypt with /dev/urandom keys. Other solutions with ‘offsets’ for metadata seem less sensible to me.

The LUKS approach is ~ the same for every partition, whether swap or data. However, LUKS is a container and thus possibly a bit more sensitive to errors. The approach with dm-crypt works... until the kernel decides to assign a different name to ‘/dev/sda6’, for example because a SATA cable is loose. In that case, the command ‘mkswap’ at boot time can be devastating to other data. That command also removes the option to assign a ‘label’ or a ‘UUID’. That, I think, leaves only the option ‘/dev/disk/by-id/DrivePartitionID’, where ‘find -L /dev/disk -samefile /dev/sda6’ produces usable IDs.

updated the answer with luks and uuid, which should address your concerns.
But if you consider the question answered, please accept the answer :)

The usual recommendation is to mount the encrypted swap by label. It's the only thing guaranteed not to change.

A swap file based on LUKS or dm-crypt. The preferred choice is dm-crypt. The main arguments for that choice:

dm-crypt is very easy to configure.
LUKS, with its container construction, is excellent for data partitions but overkill for /swap and hard to configure.
Initialisation of dm-crypt uses command mkswap and is fast where LUKS takes a bit longer.

The following is the configuration, using an example:
Inventory: no LVM and an unformatted partition nvme0n1p5, all commands as root.
What do we have?
lsblk

returns:
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
└─nvme0n1p5 259:7 0 111.8G 0 part  

More specifically:
lsblk -f /dev/nvme0n1p5

returns:
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1p5

Find an ID:
find -L /dev/disk -samefile /dev/nvme0n1p5

returns:
/dev/disk/by-id/nvme-BRAND_SPECS-part5

Edit crypttab and fstab:
nano /etc/crypttab

add this entry:
#TARGET SOURCE                                 KEYFILE      OPTIONS
encswap /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-BRAND_SPECS-part5 /dev/urandom plain,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,hash=sha1,swap

then:
nano /etc/fstab

add this entry:
/dev/mapper/encswap none swap sw 0 0

And that's basically all, so:
reboot

